# Facebook Recommendation API not returning all fields

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-recommendations

I am trying to implement the Facebook Recommendation API from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/recommendation), however in the sample they have just written  `GET v3.2/...?fields={fieldname_of_type_Recommendation}`. What is the exact endpoint to be called to get the recommendations along with all its fields?

I used Ratings API earlier `/v3.0/{page-id}/ratings` but that does not returns the "Reactions Count" and "Comments Count" which I get for posts, I want that for Recommendations as well. Any help on how to get it?

Comment: Does this help https://www.reviewsmaker.com/api/demo/recommendations/ ?

Comment: Thanks but no, I want the count of reactions and comments that have happened on each recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is

[https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{page_id}/ratings?access_token={page_access_token}&fields=reviewer{id,name,picture.width(120).height(120)},created_time,rating,recommendation_type,review_text](https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/%7Bpage_id%7D/ratings?access_token=%7Bpage_access_token%7D&fields=reviewer%7Bid,name,picture.width(120).height(120)%7D,created_time,rating,recommendation_type,review_text)

the '...' should be replace with '{page_id}/ratings'